# Enable mocha-junit-reporter in a custom runner

Tags: codeceptjs

So, when running commands with codeceptjs you can pass the --reporter flag and then the type:
codeceptjs run --reporter mocha-junit-reporter --steps

I have had to make a custom runner for some out of the box thinking, which works great. The last thing I need is to be able to tell the script that it is to use the reporter. The config file is setup with the reporter info I want, but that doesn't actually say use it in the execution. I am assuming that it is going to be in this line, in the options.
const codecept = new Codecept(codeceptConf.config, options);
But, I don't know the format needed or what its actually looking at. for example the flag --steps is changed to step:true in the options.

Thank you,

--Daniel

I need to know the format of how to pass a reporter to the custom runner.